# When completing the form at myapps.developer.ubuntu.com, should I change the Suggested package name?

Tags: application-development

I am wanting to upload my application to the Ubuntu software center and noticed that the suggested package name looks like a Windows file path, e.g. c:\myappname

Should I/does this need changing?

I am completing the form at myapps.developer.ubuntu.com...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish. The reviewers may not be able to use the suggested name, but will try if you suggest one. The existing name in there is a known bug, but low priority since that field is only a suggestion.